# How to do MongoDB case-insensitive search for single field only?

Tags: mongodb

So, case is simple. I want to have case-insensitive search on a field `name`. Luckily, latest Mongo brings us concept of collation & collation indexes.

That will easily work with something like:

```
db.users.find({ name: 'John' }).collation({ locale: 'en', strength: 2 })
```

And I have backing index for that fields with given collation strength - very efficient.

However, if I want to limit search within some stricter scope, e.g. having some `companyId` constant, things become a bit messy:

```
db.users.find({ companyId: 'some-company-id', name: 'John' }).collation({ locale: 'en', strength: 2 })
```

That collation applies both for name AND `some-company-id`. So it will look as well for `SOME-COMPANY-ID` and `SoMe-CoMpAnY-iD`, which may lead to undesired collisions, and since all cases matches, any supporting index on `companyId` does not help.

My question is: **How can I effectively search with only 1 string field being case-insensitive**?

Possible answer could be something like regex-search:

```
db.users.find({ companyId: 'some-company-id', name: /^John$/i })
```

...but unfortunately this search can't be supported by any index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, after long discussions, googling, trying to reach mongoDB team, we decided that there's nothing more reliable & transparent then supporting separate field for indexed search, like `name_lowercase`.

1. It's very transparent.
2. You can manage invariant in a way you want.
3. But you have to support it in your codebase.
4. Doubled data & index requires more disk space & network bandwidth.

But if you actually need to do it for one specific case, do it this way.